# What are the needs of Muslim teens in non-Muslim homes?

Tags: practical-islam, non-muslim-countries

I am working with a student exchange program. Some of the students living overseas (I'm in the USA) will most likely be living in non-Muslim homes.  What accommodations need to be made for the students?  I know pig meat is forbidden.  Is attendance at the mosque mandatory? What religious holidays are observed? I doubt halal meat will be available (though I could be wrong).  Is that a problem?

Comment: Nice project. Are the students more than 18, and where do they come from ?

Answer (score -2):

There are two possibilities. 
1) They should be housed in Muslim houses. 
2) The host should be made aware of the requirements and restrictions, and if they agree to willingly, then only, these students should be accommodated there. There are plenty of good people in the USA who would be more than willing to do that.

Although, preferable course would be to house them in Muslim houses. As living with the non-Muslims is fraught will perils. There is lots of material available on this topic in literature and even on the Net. For further insight into this topic one may read the following:---https://shakir2.wordpress.com/2015/05/03/save-the-generations-from-becoming-disillusioned-2/

Comment: What kind of "perils" are more present in non muslim families than in muslim ones ?